# property does not have a setter

Tags: php, phalcon

I am using a PHP / phalcon app. I have 2 copies. In server 1, I have no problems. In Server 2 (Same Code) I getting the following error.

`property '<property_name>' does not have a setter`

Since I have same code I am confused what to do here. I looked into php.ini error reporting as well, Since this error looks like a php complaining about the my code.

But in both places I dont have `~STRICT`.

```
class ClassName { 
    protected $email = null; 
}
```

from outside I do,

```
$cls = new ClassName(); 
$cls->email = 'email';
```

In this case, The error I get is

> property 'email' does not have a setter

Comment: what's the '<property_name>' name value actually?

Comment: `class ClassName {
    private $email= null;
}`

from outside I do,

`$cls = new ClasasName();
$cls->email = 'email';`

In this case, The error I get is `property 'email' does not have a setter`

Comment: Just add setter or change visibility to public, don't know why you don't have the same error on 1st server.

You defined property it's private. So why i access it outside of class ? Obviously it doesn't work. Learn OOP before using framework.

Comment: I know. I problem is that how it works in the Server 1. Probably it should be some kind of a server setting. Not sure what.

Comment: Sry the variable is `protected`. not `private`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сheck phalcon version on your servers. I had the same problem on my local host with Phalcon 2.0.13 and on server I had Phalcon 2.0.6.

Comment: You were exactly right. Thank you. This error is not there with Phalcon 2.0.10, but it comes with 20.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `protected` variable is to restrict direct access to the variable from outside of your `ClassName`.

To access a `protected` variable you will have to `extend` your `ClassName` with a `get` or a `set` function

```
class ClassName { 
    protected $email = null;

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    } 

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

You can use this as follows:

```
$cls = new ClassName(); 
$cls->setEmail('email@example.com');

echo $cls->getEmail(); // outputs: "email@example.com"
```

If you don't want the hustle of creating these `getters` and `setters` you can just change your `protected` variable to a `public` variable.

On a side note:
Are you sure your code is 100% the same?
Maybe there is an inconsistancy between your [error reporting levels](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?
What are the PHP versions on your 2 environments?
Maybe your `ClassName` has ( or inherits ) the [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) `__get` and `__set`?

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
>   __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

Comment: This is really strange. I checked the magic methods. I dont have any overridden methods. Does these magic methods to be enabled in PHP or Phalcon or Apache... in order to use them?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I change in my model `protected $email`
to `public $email` and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a magic setter ?
I had the same problem when upgrading from Phalcon 2 to 3 and got it fixed with below instead of adding all the setters manually.

```
/**
 * Magic setter function to get rid of 
 * '[Property] does not have a setter' error
 * 
 * @param any value of $field
 * @param any value of $value
 * @return no return
 */

public function __set($field, $value) {
    $this->$field = $value;
}
```